# Strange behavior when dividing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, operators

Quick question but it's making me crazy:

isn't this:

```
return c*(t/=d/2)*t*t + b;
```

the same as:

```
t = t/d/2;
return c*(t)*t*t + b;
```

Because it seems like it's not, I'm getting different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The / operator is left-associative. This means that

```
t = t/d/2;
```

Is the same as:

```
t = (t/d)/2;
```

Of course,

```
t /= d/2;
```

works out to:

```
t = t/(d/2);
```

Documentation for Actionscript: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f68

Comment: I see... so t/(d/2) is different than t/d/2. I can't understand why, mathematically they should be the same.

Comment: Well, (t/d)/2 is certainly different from t/(d/2), in any sort of math. E.g.: (400/4)/2 = 100/2 = 50, 400/(4/2) = 400/2 = 200. t/d/2 is ambiguous unless you resolve this ambiguity by choosing a direction. Note that if you wrote this in conventional mathematical notation you would have to make it clear which you meant.

Comment: Yeah, I remembered now, for some reason I thought that dividing was the same as multiplying for 1/number. Like, if you want to divide by 2 is the same as multiplying by 1/2. And then I associated that with the fact that multiplication is commutative.